# vb6 - C API - Mysql Embedded Server - Assertion Failed

Tags: mysql, vb6

According to the documentation while liking to libmysqld.dll after calling the function through vb6 first mysql_server_init and then calling mysql_init

```
 argv = {
           "test",
           "--datadir=" & Replace(App.Path, "\", "/") & "/sql/data",
           "--basedir=" & Replace(App.Path, "\", "/") & "/sql",
           "--no-defaults",
           "--skip-networking"
       }     

  groups   = {
                "embedded",
                "server",
                "test_SERVER"
             }

 if mysql_server_init ( argc , argv , groups ) then
       mysql = mysql_init(0)   <==  Causing problem [ pic error message]
 else
     MsgBox "Init not Done".
 end if
```

Mysql Version : 5.1.32

libmysqld.dll [Debug] - Gives the following message

libmysqld.dll [release] - Crashes no error message

Public Declare Function mysql_init Lib "libmySQLd" (ByVal lMYSQL As Long) As Long

-

[image: Error Assertion Failed]

Comment: How is `mysql_init` declared?

Comment: @GSerg added as

Comment: The [seems correct](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-init.html) and should work with `0`. What should not work though is the call to `mysql_server_init`, at least because it returns non-zero for a failure and you handle that case as success (and you should not need to call it at all because it's deprecated in the favor of [mysql_library_init](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-library-init.html) which is called by `mysql_init` as necessary).

Comment: @gserg in Ver 5.1.32 mysql_library_init is not available and other thing the error is log.cc assertion failure which I don't understand why showing